# Замена подстроки на строку меньшего размера

Tags: c, строки

Программа просит на ввод строку,если в ней встречаются подстроки

- "www.facebook.com"
- "facebook.com"
- "vk.com"
- "www.vk.com"

Должна быть произведена  замена на ***, как показано в примере (What is better, vk.com or  facebook.com? → What is better, ***  or ***?)
Реализация должна быть с помощью стандартных функций библиотеки string.h.
Не выходит решение этой задачи из-за того что функция strncpy копирует в подстроки всего-лишь 3 символа,и выходит вот такая вот штука What is better, ***com or  ***ebook.com?
Как это можно поправить?(Предполагаю что стоит копировать введенную строку в буфер и дальше с ней какие-то махинации проводить)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int read_line(char adress[], int n);
int antisn(char* adress);

int main() {
char adress[300];

printf("Input adress: ");
read_line(adress, 300);
antisn(adress);
}


int read_line(char adress[], int n) {
int ch, i = 0;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    if (i < n)
        adress[i++] = ch;

adress[i] = '\0';
return i;
}




int antisn(char* adress) {
char* vk;
char* wvk;
char* fb;
char* wfb;

wvk = strstr(adress, "www.vk.com"); 
if (wvk != NULL) {
    strncpy(wvk, "***", 3);
}



wfb = strstr(adress, "www.facebook.com");
if (wfb != NULL) {
    strncpy(wfb, "***", 3);
    }



vk = strstr(adress, "vk.com");
 if (vk != NULL) {
    strncpy(vk, "***", 3);
    }

fb = strstr(adress, "facebook.com");
if (fb != NULL) {
    strncpy(fb, "***", 3);
}

if (vk == NULL && wvk == 0 && fb == 0 && wfb == 0)
    printf("Nety");
else
    puts(adress);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: После того как звёздочки вставили, надо "хвост" строки "подтянуть". Придётся копировать посимвольно. Стандарт запрещает для этого использовать `strcpy`.

Comment: В мыслях то я понимаю что и как, и этот вариант тоже рассматривал)) Но как это в коде реализовать?

Comment: Было бы не плохо если бы вы это в коде продемонстрировали

Comment: Для "подтягивания хвоста" используйте [memmove](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `replace` заменяет подстроку на более короткую. Для "подтягивания" хвоста используется [memmove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove). Это единственная функция которая умеет копировать перекрывающиеся участки памяти:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void replace(char *text, const char *old, const char *new) {
    assert(strlen(old) >= strlen(new));

    char *p = strstr(text, old); 
    if (p != NULL) {
        memcpy(p, new, strlen(new));
        memmove(p + strlen(new), p + strlen(old), strlen(p + strlen(old)) + 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    char text[] = "https://www.vk.com/path";
    replace(text, "www.vk.com", "***");
    puts(text);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое